# geom_hline not working properly with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

When defining a `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` in `ggplot2` (version 2), and drawing a subsequent `geom_hline` - the `ggplot` figure correctly draws a horizontal line through all x points, but fails to do so using the `ggplotly` wrapper.

```
library(plotly)
g = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
g = g + geom_hline(yintercept=3.5, color = "red")
g
(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```

Does anyone know how to create straight lines using `ggplotly` through all x points?

Comment: Would this maybe help https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_point/#add-horizontal-line-with-geom_segment

Comment: @drmariod I tried that, but it doesn't work and is not a general solution

Comment: Works for me. Looks a bit different (grid is different and the lines are thicker, but it definitely works)

Comment: You should add your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't work in Shiny. Session info: R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) ; plotly_2.0.19 ; ggplot2_2.0.0.9000.

Comment: it works outside Shiny (for me) so maybe you should post your Shiny code as well.